# Windows service in C# using microsoft graph using Parallel.Invoke is in running state but not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, microsoft-graph-api

In windows service we are connecting to multiple mailboxes using Microsoft graph, reading mails and downloading attachments.
We are using separate class for each mailbox and calling each class with Parallel.Invoke() method.

```
Parallel.Invoke(() =>
{                       
    ParallelThreadOne.MainAsync().Wait();
},
() =>
{                       
    ParallelThreadSecond.MainAsync().Wait();
});
```

In each thread we are calling Microsoft Graph's `GraphServiceClient` to get a user token to process further.

Problems:

1. Windows service running fine but after some time service is in running state but not doing anything and logging also stops.
2. After restarting the service it works normally with logging.
3. The service should be running 24x7.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do the MainAsync() methods terminate? May they throw exceptions?

Comment: If you are in that state attach a debugger and take a look.

Comment: @KlausGütter There are no exceptions as service is still running but not doing functionalities. Service runs well for few days, before stopping working

Answer (score 2):

PLEASE use async and await (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern, TAP). Please read about Task.Run() i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-5.0.

Wait for multiple tasks:

```
var task1 = DoWorkAsync();
var task2 = DoMoreWorkAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

Generally you need an interactive login with GraphServiceClient in the first place and may cache this (token). Interactive logins are not possible with Windows services, because of the underlying security sandbox (session 0) which prevents showing forms.

Hint: use a normal console application (or windows forms app) for the login task, cache the token (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-token-cache-serialization?tabs=custom) and read it back in your service.

Regards